# ActionBar actionView item style

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme

I am trying to create a popup on the actionbar item (like the one in G+ app).

To do this, I need to have the actionbar item view but this is available only setting a custom view with `setActionView()`.

The problem is that I cannot reach the same menu item style of actionbar items.

I am using this:

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?android:attr/actionButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
    android:paddingRight="12dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_refresh">
```

but the result is not good.

Where could I find a layout/style to mimic the action bar item one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use this layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton"
             android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh">

</ImageButton>
```

with the style `@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton`